# Create few style for QPushButton in .qss

Tags: css, qt

My problem is that I want create few styles for QPushButton, for example, I create two QPushButton 's:

```
QPushButton *next; 
QPushButton *prev;
```

And I want "next" with green background, and "prev" in blue background, so I wrote in .qss file:

//.qss file

```
QPushButton
{
background-color: green;
}
```

But of course when I compile it, all elements of QPushButtons are green, how can I make one green and one blue etc.?

This is just simple example what my point is.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to use the appropriate selectors. The selector `QPushButton` refers to all elements of type `QPushButton` or its subclasses.

Give a name to your buttons using `QObject::setObjectName()` and then you can select them by ID in the style sheet just like in CSS.

Lets use the same variable names you used in the question:

**C++**

```
next->setObjectName("next");
prev->setObjectName("prev");
```

**Style sheet**

```
#next {
  background-color: green;
}
#prev {
  background-color: red;
}
```

More information on selector types and style sheet syntax in general can be found [here](http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-5/stylesheet-syntax.html).